# change a point's position with a slider?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider, wpf-controls

I'm new at c sharp and I have a problem in my wpf project.
how can I change a point's position by dragging a slider?
I tried to use this but it didn't work

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Line Name="Sa"/>
    <Line Name="Sb"/>
    <Line Name="Oa"/>
    <Line Name="Ob"/>
    <Slider Name="Slid1" Margin="78,51,1002,332" IsDirectionReversed="False" IsMoveToPointEnabled="False" Maximum="100" Minimum="-100" IsEnabled="True" />
</Grid>
```

and these codes behind:

```
InitializeComponent();
Sa = new Line();
Sa.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
Sa.X1 = Slid1.Value;
Sa.X2 = window.Width / 2;
Sa.Y1 = (window.Height) / 2;
Sa.Y2 = window.Height / 2 -50;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign Sa.X1 the Slid1.Value as a compile-time constant value.
You will have to implement a listener for the slider.ValueChanged event to refresh the value.

it should look like:

> Slider.ValueChanged += new Eventlistener(RefreshPosition)

and

> RefreshPosition(object sender, ValueChangedEventargs args)
>   {
>   Sa.X1 = sender.value;
>   }

// if this won't compile, you need to cast sender to slider.. (e.g. 'sender as Slider')

The whole suggestion is pseudo-code only. You also might want to encapsule Sa.X1 with a property..

EDIT: corrected name of event (thanks XAMIMAX)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code behind then use code below

```
Sa.X1 = Slid1.Value;
Sa.X2 = window.Width / 2;
Sa.Y1 = (window.Height) / 2;
Sa.Y2 = window.Height / 2 -50;
```

in the event handler of the `Slider.ValueChanged` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Sa.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    Slid1.ValueChanged += Slid1_ValueChanged;           
}

void Slid1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{            
    Sa.X1 = slider.Value;
    Sa.X2 = window.Width / 2;
    Sa.Y1 = (window.Height) / 2;
    Sa.Y2 = window.Height / 2 - 50;
}
```

If you do this

```
Sa = new Line();
```

you are creating a new instance of Line. This is only necessary for example in java to do on your own. In C# all this is done by the application itself.